# I find driver root Symfony Error, how I can solve it?

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, xampp, driver

While trying to run the server I get this error and I didn't know how to solve it,

> The given 'driver' root is unknown, Doctrine currently supports only the following drivers: pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, pdo_pgsql, pdo_oci, oci8, ibm_db2, pdo_sqlsrv, mysqli, pgsql, sqlsrv, sqlite3

I have already activated the extensions in XAMPP like pdo_mysql....

And I still have the same error

Comment: have you looked at your .env? env can be defined in multiple ways  ... find the way that applies.

Comment: show your DATABASE_URI from .env

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem directly related to MySQL, PDO, or XAMPP? To me, this looks more like a typo